# threejs explode/implode model

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm newbie threejs and WebGL.
I'm using three.js to load Obj file.

I want to explode/implode the production like this [image]

I created an example. However, It's not working now.

```
model.vertices.forEach(function(v) {
     v.velocity = Math.random();
});
```

see codepen https://codepen.io/nxhoang/pen/xjjmzO
In above example, I can get model and change position by

```
const parts = object.children;
parts[0].position.setX(100);
```

However, problem is how to know direction of parts to go.

I found some examples for exploding and imploding http://www.vatelier.net/tests/threejs-cookbook-master/06-particles-postprocessing/06.06-explode-geometry.html but I don't know how to apply to my case.

Thanks for any helps,

Comment: Please include any relevant code in your post. When (not if) your link becomes invalid, then your question loses important context.

Comment: Another example https://codepen.io/nxhoang/pen/xjjmzO